# What can I use to seam a quartz countertop besides epoxy?

Tags: quartz

Is there something else that can be used for  a quartz counter top seam without using strong epoxy or chemicals. I am very sensitive to chemicals. Or can silicone be used instead?

Comment: I think if you're ok with a visible seam that could possibly move a little over time, you could use just about anything.  Is that OK with you?

Comment: You know that literally everything is chemicals, right? Maybe you could be more specific about your concerns.

Comment: A quartz countertop will be there forever. The tiny amount of seam material will be inert and odor-free within minutes, and typically doesn't have outrageous fumes even during use. If you are doing the job yourself and are extremely sensitive, wear gloves and a mask for the few minutes it will take. If a contractor will be doing the job and you don't hover, you are likely to be unaware that "chemicals" were even involved, and there is no long-term odor, or chemicals that leach out. Just use the best materials for the job; the "chemicals" are too minimal and momentary to be a consideration.

Answer (score 2):

Find an adhesive that is Greenguard Gold Certified

GREENGUARD Certification  helps buyers identify interior products and materials that have low chemical emissions, improving the quality of the air in which the products are used.

GREENGUARD Gold Certification (formerly known as GREENGUARD Children & Schools Certification) offers stricter certification criteria, considers safety factors to account for sensitive individuals (such as children and the elderly), and ensures that a product is acceptable for use in environments such as schools and healthcare facilities.

If there is a specific chemical that you are sensitive to you can get the data sheet for the adhesive to see if it contains that chemical.

Answer (score 0):

use clear silicon calk. I have theses exact counter 
tops.